# Why is the com.android.browser process draining my battery?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, battery-life

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note with stock 4.0.4 ROM. The battery drains very fast and the phone is often warm. Reboot doesn't help. Settings says that com.android.browser (Internet) uses most of the battery. I never use default browser, I only use Chrome.

I suspect that some background process it creating a heavy load and using the internet connection. I think browser is used by other applications, but I'm not able to figure out which application is related. I suspect maybe ad supported applications are the root of the problem.

Is there any solution or app to figure out the origin of the problem?

Comment: Have you tried switching to the default browser instead of Chrome? Is there a newer version of Chrome for ICS?

Comment: As I wrote, I have no problem with Chrome. The main energy consumer is the default android browser.

Comment: I also saw this on an S4 mini with essentially no sync options enabled. It does seem to get stuck in something. Some posts advice clearing the cache and closing tabs. I'm not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is Internet sync related. The system is not able to sync internet settings.

http://blog.abrah.am/2011/12/sync-is-currently-experiencing-problems.html

Answer (score 0):

While I can't speculate as to the exact reason, you may find the app Better Battery Stats useful in working out where the battery drain is coming from.

The app is able to define kernel wakelocks, partial wakelocks and cpu states etc. Very useful in helping myself pinpointing problematic applications and extending battery life.

The app can be installed as a .apk provided for free by the developer over at [xda-dev](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809) or supporting the author by purchasing the [paid app from the Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats&hl=en)